# cannot assign a value of type json to a value of type NSArray

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to send some info with a segue but I get the following error
**cannot assign a value of type json to a value of type NSArray**

When I try to do:

```
self.pageImages = apiResult["images"]
```

I have apiResult setup as:

```
var apiResult: JSON! = []
```

Then I'm using alamofire together with swiftyjson in order to fetch the result and cast it to json, but now I need it as an NSArray.

My data is returned as:

```
{
    "somedata": {
        some info
    },
    "someData": {
        some info..
    },
    "images": [
       "URL1", "URL2", "URL3"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `apiResult` is the JSON object returned by SwiftyJSON and if `apiResult["images"]` is the array of URLs you want to assign to your `pageImages` array variable, then you have to use the `array` property of the JSON typed SwiftyJSON object:

```
self.pageImages = apiResult["images"].array
```

Comment: I've tried that before but it didn't work. But now I found another called ".arrayObject" which worked :)

Comment: Yes, the SwiftyJSON library has many optional an non-optional "getters", which one to use depends on the nature of your JSON content: `.array`, `.arrayValue`, `.arrayObject` and so on, same for dictionaries, strings, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your array definition is setup to accept value of type `JSON` - what you want is to accept value of type `[JSON]` - i.e., an array of JSON values.

`var apiResult: [JSON!] = []`

Additionally, I'm not sure why you'd need implicitly unwrapped optionals unless you have a good reason for it?

Also, Swift has type inference. So if your values being returned are an array of JSON objects, then the compiler knows that and you don't have to explicitly tell it a value type.